# Converting a sequences of images to a video with ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm trying ffmpeg to convert sequence of images to a single video, but nothing happened and no any error message is shown. Below is the shell command I've used (invoked via PHP's [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec)):

```
ffmpeg -i events/dream_theatre.jpg events/output.avi &
```

I just want to test first with single image and trying this in shared hosting server. No error message or any message is shown with this. I've a root access to server machine.

Comment: You should get your `ffmpeg` command working first, then attempt to use in with PHP. Your command shows a single image for input, but you mention that you're trying create a video from a sequence of images. How many images are there and are they all named similarly?

Comment: As you've written that you don't see any error message, reporting most likely starts with `-loglevel verbose` or `-loglevel debug`. You find these and more explained with the ffmpeg usage instructions which you should read before wondering: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html